# Active class with custom wp_get_archives HTML output

Tags: wp-get-archives

I use a filter on `get_archives_link` for the HTML output and I try to reproduce the default `aria-current="page"` attribute on the `<a>` tag when we are on the archive page.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'o2_archives_html' ) ) :
    function o2_archives_html( $link_html, $url, $text, $format, $before, $after ) {

        if ( 'html' === $format )
        $link_html = "\t<li>$before<a href='$url'><span class='label'><span class='title'>$text</span></span></a>$after</li>\n";

        return $link_html;

    }
endif; // o2_archives_html()
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'o2_archives_html', 10, 6 );
```

I would like to put an "active" class on the `<li class="active">` tag when we are for example on February 2022 `site.com/blog/2022/02/page/2/`.

What condition does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an easy way but here is a solution:

I get the month and year from the current archive and compare them with the text.

```
$year      = get_query_var( 'year' );
$monthnum  = get_query_var( 'monthnum' );
$monthname = $GLOBALS['wp_locale']->get_month( $monthnum );
$date      = $monthname . ' ' . $year;

if ( $text === $date )
$active_class = 'class="current-menu-item"';
```